# Python Regex instantly replace groups

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

Is there any way to directly replace all groups using regex syntax?

The normal way:

```
re.match(r"(?:aaa)(_bbb)", string1).group(1)
```

But I want to achieve something like this:

```
re.match(r"(\d.*?)\s(\d.*?)", "(CALL_GROUP_1) (CALL_GROUP_2)")
```

I want to build the new string instantaneously from the groups the Regex just captured.

Answer (score 320, accepted):

Have a look at [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
result = re.sub(r"(\d.*?)\s(\d.*?)", r"\1 \2", string1)
```

This is Python's regex substitution (replace) function. The replacement string can be filled with so-called backreferences (backslash, group number) which are replaced with what was matched by the groups. Groups are counted the same as by the `group(...)` function, i.e. starting from `1`, from left to right, by opening parentheses.

Comment: Way more clear than the doc! Did not understand how group was working with this one. They should add such example.

Comment: it worked from the firsttime, This is a pretty good clear way to explain it. Thanks and can you explain how the sub group should be calling in proper way `(r(r))r((r)((r)r))` kinda situation ?

Comment: @RakshithaMurangaRodrigo The groups are numbered from left to right, going by where they start. So if I insert each group's number right in front of the group, they'd be sorted: `1(r2(r))r3(4(r)5(6(r)r))`.

Comment: You can also provide a name for a group using this notation: `(?P<group-name><pattern>)` and then reference them in this way: `\g<group-name>` . This is the most convenient way IMHO.

Comment: but what is string1 ? I mean where do you put replacement values ?

Comment: The `r` prefix solved my problem

Comment: Note: I don't think there is any purpose to your '?' in your regex...
You already said (\d.*) which means any decimal digit and 0 or more any characters.
* (0 or more) automatically means optional..

Comment: @MarshallJobe `?` after `*` does not mean optional but it makes the `*` ungreedy. That said, it's still unnecessary in this case (and probably even a bad idea), but I just reused the exact regex from the question, since the focus was on the substitution.

Comment: @MartinEnder I see, thanks... forgot about ungreedy

Answer (score 79):

The accepted answer is perfect. I would add that group reference is probably better achieved by using this syntax:

```
r"\g<1> \g<2>"
```

for the replacement string. This way, you work around syntax limitations where a group may be followed by a digit. Again, this is all present in the doc, nothing new, just sometimes difficult to spot at first sight.

Comment: If you want to add a number after a group this is the way to go, otherwise, it messes up the number value with the group ordinal.