# How to replace the space that follows a digit into comma using python and re package?

Tags: python-3.x

How to replace the space that follows a digit into comma using python and re?

For example,

0,   1,   0   12   13 -> 0,   1,   0,   12,   13;

```
import re

text = "0, 1, 0 12 13"    
matches = re.sub(r'(\d+)\s','*,', text)
print(matches)
```

but that gives me 
0,   1,   *,   *,   *,

Comment: You need to replace the `*` with `\1` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007545/python-regex-instantly-replace-groups/14007559

Comment: Thank you very much! It works like a magic. :

Answer (score 0):

Another way, without re:

```
text = "0, 1, 0 12 13" 
text = text.replace(',', '') #We remove the commas (to leave them all the same)
text.replace(' ', ', ')      # We replace spaces by comma and space
```

Comment: Thanks Ibellomo, but the spaces between these digits are arbitrary. Zero's solution turns out to be very useful. re.sub(r"(\d+)\s",  r"\1,",  tex).

Comment: I do not know `re` and that's why I avoid them.