# Find http links and put between tags in Python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am a novice in Python (I am using Python 3.7). I am trying to create a script to scrap some text from web-page, clean it from tags and make into readable document. I want to find all links (that start with "http") and put them between pair of tags TeX \textbf{ and }, so those links show up in bold in final doc.
I found a piece of code to find a word that start from specific character.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "Lorem ipsum text lorem ipsum text  http:\\link.xyz some random text here."
>>> re.findall(r'\[h]\w+', text)
```

What I would like to get is:

```
>>> text = "Lorem ipsum text lorem ipsum text  \textbf{http:\\link.xyz} some random text here."
```

Sorry for clumsy code example. Help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: These links will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007545/python-regex-instantly-replace-groups https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url

Comment: The code with `re`means that you are looking for a regular expression. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883049/regex-to-find-urls-in-string-in-python. On this link you may get  all url and then append `\textbf{` at the begining and then `}`at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stitching together the regular expression from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3809435/4822566) with the [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) method (and fixing your link to use the correct slash), gives us this:

```
>>> import re
>>> link_finder = re.compile(r"https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)")
>>> text = "Lorem ipsum text lorem ipsum text  http://link.xyz some random text here."
>>> link_finder.sub(lambda link_match: "\\textbf{{{0}}}".format(link_match.group(0)), text)
'Lorem ipsum text lorem ipsum text  \\textbf{http://link.xyz} some random text here.'
```

Note the double back-slash is a formatting (escaping) detail, and won't be shown on your output.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! May I ask what is the role of the "lambda function" in this code?

Comment: `sub` replaces the matched text with either a supplied string _or_ the result of a function (the lambda). That lambda accepts the `re.Match` that is going to be replaced. In this example, the matched text is used as part of the returned value which is then placed into the original string.