# Regex for matching square brackets and number

Tags: python, regex

I have a sentence somewhat like this

> Example.[1]

I am trying to write a sentence to leave me with just Example. I currently have

```
cleanr = re.compile('[\[0-9]\]')
cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_html)
```

and get

Example.

However, if I have any numbers 0-9 anywhere else, they dissapear. How do I remove only things of the form [0-9] without moving lose numereicals outside of brackets, or removing brackets that don't contain a single digit within? ie, I only want to remove things such as [0], [1], [2], [3], ... [9], but not [0Something4].

Comment: Use `\[\d]` or `\[\d+]`

Comment: I think one of those backslashes is misplaced -- should be `\[[0-9]\]` or just `\[\d\]`

Comment: Also, this is how to [**match a dot**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989640/regular-expression-to-match-a-dot).

Comment: [Regex : matching integers inside of brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59793742/regex-matching-integers-inside-of-brackets) is only a partial duplicate but not-so-well-defined problem with no source code. If needed that question can be closed a dupe of current one.

Comment: Right, partial of the first, partial of the second, and it is a [case described by Code Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405053/should-a-question-without-source-code-in-it-be-closed#comment823358_405057) where you do not need to connect any more than 2 "dots".

Comment: We often assume that connecting 2 or more dots might be quite easy. When it is not. Not for me at least when starting fresh with a technology.

Comment: There is adding `\.` + `\[\d+]`, **what is not evident here**
?

Comment: I understand the points made here. My view on this is if there is an exact dupe which exists, then we can close the question. However if there isn't any , we should let OP have their deserved answer. Whilst I am for - maintaining the sanity of any tag, however not at the cost of user experience. Ultimately we are a Q&A site. I may be wrong but that's my layman view.

Comment: Then there was no point of implementing multiple duplicate feature.

Comment: Attaching 2 different links to a question and this answer is providing answer with both the functionalities, now what makes site better user experience? 1- An answer(this one) which has complete answer(OP's question), 2- Or adding 2 different links where OP has to search for the answers. Anyone will go for 1st option in terms of Good user experience.  BTW these were NOT 2 same dupes they are link with 2 different solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
import re
value='Example.[1]'
re.sub(r"\.\[\d+\]",'',value)
```

***Explanation:*** Importing `re` library of python here. Then creating a sample variable named value which has `Example.[1]` in it. Now as per OP substituting `.`(DOT) `[` followed by 1 or more occurrences of digits `]` with NULL in value.

Comment: Attached dupe was not exact one because it's not handling dot capturing in regex.