# Regex check if a string has any numbers followed by units in python and modify it

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to clean some data including texts like '6cm*8cm', '6cmx8cm', and '6*8'. I want to modify them so that they become similar.  Notice that numbers are changeable, so the data may have '3cm*4cm' etc.

```py
# input strings
strings = [
    "6cm*8cm",
    "12mmx15mm",
    'Device stemmer 2mm*8mm',
    'Device stemming 2mmx8mm'
]
# My desired output would be:
desired_strings = [
    '6*8',
    '12*15',
    'Device stemmer 2*8',
    'Device stemming 2*8'
]
```

I am using python's 're'. My preference is to convert them to a simple '6*8' (i.e, number*number). Note that in some of the entries data has strings like: 'Device stemmer 2mm*8mm', and I do not want to change other words.

Is there a pythonic way with regex to modify all the possible combinations of numbers and units paired with each other?

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```py
import re

strings = [
    "6cm*8cm",
    "12mmx15mm",
    'Device stemmer 2mm*8mm',
    'Device stemming 2mmx8mm'
]

for i in strings:
    result = re.sub(r"([0-9]+)(cm|mm)(\*|x)([0-9]+)(cm|mm)", r"\1*\4", i)
    print(result)
```

Notes:
`([0-9]+)`: matches numbers,
`(cm|mm)`: matches units and `|` stands for logical `OR`,
`(\*|x)`: matches `\*` or `x` as the separator of pairs,
`\1`: gives the first group (here the first number e.g., 6),
`\4`: gives the fourth group (here the second number e.g., 8)

https://regex101.com/ and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007545/python-regex-instantly-replace-groups/14007559) helped.

Comment: You only need 2 capturing groups as you don't need to keep what you are going to replace, and you could use a character class `[cm]m` and `[*x]` instead of the alternations `([0-9]+)[cm]m[*x]([0-9]+)[cm]m` https://regex101.com/r/olVPIG/1