# Replace the value located between two commas in Regex python

Tags: python, regex

I've two string that and I would like to replace the numbers that located after the first comma in the first []. Please note that the numbers may change and are not fixed numbers.

However, I could change the numbers for `phase_y`. but in `phase_x` it replace the first two number after that comma and also replace the numbers that located after the [Ego: which i don't want that. I would like to see the other numbers remain expect the first two numbers after in the first []. I don't know why is my regex works for the phase_y and not works for the phase_x. any hlep?

```
import os
import random
 
import re
 

 
phase_x = "PHASE 1: [Drive_Towards] [-, 24 to 34, -4 to -3][Ego: -10 to 0, FSR]"
phase_y = "PHASE 1: [Walk_Towards] [-, 1 to 3, -3 to -5][Ego:-4 to -2, FSL]"
LowerValue = 10
HigherValue = 20
 
 
 
myRegex_1 = "\d+\sto\s\d+"
myRegex_2 = str(LowerValue)+" to "+ str(HigherValue)
 
 
 
new_line_phase_x = re.sub(myRegex_1, myRegex_2, phase_x)
new_line_phase_y = re.sub(myRegex_1, myRegex_2, phase_y)
 
print(new_line_phase_x)
print(new_line_phase_y)
```

Python demo [here](https://ideone.com/Jop06x)

Comment: You can try using a grouped regex, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007545/python-regex-instantly-replace-groups).

Comment: @niid I'm very much new to regex, would you please explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, you want the change only once, that also after the first [] and comma in both phase_x and phase_y. Add another parameter count=1 , in your re.sub() command to change only once.

```
new_line_phase_x = re.sub(myRegex_1, myRegex_2, phase_x,1)
new_line_phase_y = re.sub(myRegex_1, myRegex_2, phase_y,1)
```

This gives output

```
PHASE 1: [Drive_Towards] [-, 10 to 20, -4 to -3][Ego: -10 to 0, FSR]
PHASE 1: [Walk_Towards] [-, 10 to 20, -3 to -5][Ego:-4 to -2, FSL]
```